# how to get a better result if I only have a small dataset in machine learning?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, machine-learning, dataset

My project is about traffic lights recognition. I need to find where and what the traffic lights are in the image. The problem is I only have a quite small dataset because i make it by myself from image searched from internet. What shall I do?

Comment: Data Augmentation is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: This question belongs on a different Stackexchange site, like [datascience.se], or [ai.se]. Stackoverflow is only for questions directly related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TimH said, you can create new images from a database with 'Data Augmentation'. It's a typical technique in machine learning when you are working with images.